# Optimizing a Simply Query in MySql

Tags: mysql

I have what i believe to be an incredibly simple MySQL query - however, its 650ms execution time is baffling me.

**Here is what the table structure looks like:**

[image]

**Here are the indexes:**

[image]

**Here is the result from the EXPLAIN on the query:**

[image]

**Finally - here is the query itself:**

```
SELECT * FROM user_cookies as uc WHERE uc.cookie_guid = "d884b922-0fbc-48e1-b5bc-c0e3e7929f1b" AND uc.expires > now();
```

I cannot for the life of me understand why this query would be so slow - the table only contains about 70 records also. Any suggestions/thoughts/ideas would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Can you run explain() around that query? It will tell you what index it chooses. Sometimes mySql does weird index selection, especially when the table size is so small.

Comment: explain results should be showing in the original question unless you mean something different than i put in the question.

Comment: Ah yes missed that, thanks. Indeed it is selecting the cookie_guid only, and not the one with 'expires. It is probably just because the table is so small. You can run an analyze on the table to see if that helps, or add a 'force index (idxGuidAndExpire)'

Comment: so weird, do you know if there is any other way i could get the index to work - the reason i ask is because this query is being generated by an ORM and i'm not going to have the ability to force the index via the ORM... sucks :( - i did rerun analyze and tried optimize as well but the explain remains the same

Comment: actually - another interesting point, after forcing the index in the query analyze the speed remains the same at about 700ms. So odd!!

Comment: Yeah sorry I'm not sure. I do know varchar isn't great for indexes though. If there is any way to use an int instead then that will speed things up.

Comment: 70 records is nothing and unlikely is the problem related to indexes or their absence. How much time does a plain select count(*) from user_cookies take?

Comment: What's this program you're using? It doesn't have to be the case of MySQL being slow but everything around it - from your ORM / this program you provided screenshots for, network (due to a proxy or an old hub / switch / cable / whatever). At amount of records that you mentioned, indexes are completely useless. That doesn't mean you SHOULD NOT USE them, it means that MySQL probably *doesn't* have to even use it, as full table scan will be as fast. Try to use profiling. `SET PROFILING = 1; SELECT ... (your query here); SHOW PROFILE FOR QUERY 1; SET PROFILING = 0;`.

Comment: hi @Aurelion - the speed for selecting ALL records is almost exactly the same.

Comment: hi @N.B. - the program in the screenshots is Navicat - not my ORM - i'm using Entity Framework for my ORM - but right now Navicat is only executing queries - i dont believe navicat is causing the slow down - at least not 700ms worth. I've tried using the profiling following the syntax you provided however the results are empty - like no data - which is odd.

Comment: The second index is redundant btw

Comment: @Strawberry - sorry can you name the index thats redundant? do you mean the idxUserCookiesGuid